# Display Product Attribute Value only if it exists

Tags: php, magento

Surprisingly can't find anything on this... basically I call my custom product attributes on the product view page like this:

```
Men / Women: <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getmenwomen()) ?>
```

This displays the men/women attribute fine, but these are optional values, so if a product doesn't have a value for this particular attribute, the line is still displayed, just with no value:

```
Men / Women:
```

I'd like that line to not show at all if there is indeed, no value for a product. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check if the value of getmenwomen() really contains something you expect it to contain (eg men/women) before printing it. In this example i presume that anything but whitespace is a valid value.

```
$menwomen = $_product->getmenwomen();
if (trim($menwomen)) {
    echo "Men / Women: ".$this->htmlEscape($menwomen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this because I am not sure if getmenwomen() will return false if its empty
If nothing is to be returned, by default it should return false.

```
<?php
  if ($var = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getmenwomen()) {
    echo "Men / Women: " + $var;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Chris, User684736's answer seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to display everything if there is a value and nothing if there isn't?  Just add a simple conditional:

```
if (!empty($this->htmlEscape($_product->getmenwomen())))
   echo 'Men / Women: '.$this->htmlEscape($_product->getmenwomen());
```

and that's it, you don't even need an else in there.

Comment: Thanks linus but that code threw me this error - "Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context"